# Can't add templating engine in plugin HapiJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, templating-engine

I want to implement routes per plugin, but I can't add the views engine inside the plugin. I've seen examples where this is possible, E.G.: https://github.com/hapijs-edge/hapi-plugins.com/blob/master/lib/routes.js, but I'm getting an error saying `server.views is not a function`

```js
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection();

var myPlugin = {
    register: function (server, options, next) {

        // Error happens here, should be able to see server.views()
        console.log(server.views()); 
        next();
    }
};

myPlugin.register.attributes = {
    name: 'myPlugin',
    version: '1.0.0'
};

server.register( myPlugin, function(err) {

    if (err) {
        console.error('Failed to load a plugin:', err);
    }
} );

server.start(function () {

    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guys at hapi, showed me the way... as of hapi 9, vision module is required to decorate server and have access to the [views](https://github.com/hapijs/vision) method. It now works fine!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with hapi v10. Try "npm i hapi@8.8.1", that version should work

Comment: Can you give some indication of how or why to improve the quality and value of this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register vision [plugin](https://github.com/hapijs/vision) before you can use server.view function as of hapi => 9.x.x.